# How can you get the sample rate frequency of the iphone accelerometer?

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, frequency, sample-rate

Is there a function or method to get the iphone's current sampling rate of the running accelerometer?

I know how to set the iPhone accelerometer to a certain frequency, but I would like to verify that it is actually running at that frequency

It should look like this to set the accelerometer to running...

```
// Set the Accelerometer to 30 updates per second
filter = [[filterClass alloc] initWithSampleRate:30.0 cutoffFrequency:5.0];
filter.adaptive = useAdaptive;
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:1.0 / 30.0];
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];
```

Now how can we find out what the sample frequency is currently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oops.... found it..!

```
NSLog(@"updateInterval: %f", [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] updateInterval]);
```

updateInterval: 0.033333 Bang on 30 cycles per second as set!